# lua_newthread() & LUA_REGISTRYINDEX independence

Tags: c, api, lua

It's quite a simple question but has it's gotchas.So here it goes.

Does each new Lua state created using the lua_newthread C API method get it's own individual LUA_REGISTRYINDEX accessible through it's new created Lua state or does it use a global shared LUA_REGISTRYINDEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All threads of the same Lua state share a single registry, as can be seen in the [source](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstate.h.html#isLua).

Different Lua states have different registries.